# Receiving multiple files from other apps does not work as intended

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an app that receives single or multiple image files from other apps via the Share feature. The single file share intent-filter works without problems but with the multiple file I am having some issues. If I select a combination of images and any other mime-type, say PDFs then the share option lists my app. I have written the intent-filter to accept only JPEGs and PNGs. If no images are selected in the list of files to be shared then my app is NOT listed but it's the combination of images and other files that is bothering me. Below is the intent-filter that I wrote.

```
       <intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/ic_print_file_receiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Can someone help me figure out the problem? I want to avoid my app being listed when we have non JPEG/PNGs selected. Appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @greenapps - I am trying to receive images from other apps to my app. When I select a combination of images and pdfs or a combination of images or html and use the share function of other apps my app gets listed in the list of apps that can handle the mimeTypes. I don't want that. I want it to be listed only when I have images selected, not a combination of images and other mime types. The whole point of selecting mimeTypes in the intent-filter. Was it clear?

Comment: Be glad your app gets in the list always. Pllease tell what the problem is when an occasional pdf file name is in between the image file names.

Comment: Be glad? What? What is the problem? For starters, my app does not handle PDFs or anything other than JPEGs/PNGs. It's not an occasional PDF file. My app will be listed when I select 20 PDFs and 1 image file, several HTMLs, a bunch of PDFs and 1 image file. You see where I am going here? I am specifying the mimetype that my app deals with, now why would I want to have a PDF or any other mimetype other than JPEG/PNG. I can very well handle the shared files and cherry pick them but that is not an ideal solution. If there is no better way of doing this I will have to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Fine, I cherry pick and handle only images now the user is wondering what happened to the files that are not images. Now, I have to put up a dialog or a toast explaining what my app does and say "Sorry, we handle only images. :)". Now, do you see why....?

Comment: You should not bother about that. You are not alone. Many apps will be involved. The user will understand. Or learn to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through a lot of apps if found out that different apps are handling the implicit intent differently.

- I found that ESExplorer would completely disregard the intent-filter. If I pick two PDFs and share I would see my printer listed which was completely against my mime-type setting (shown above in my question).
- Another File Explorer app called BlackMoon file explorer, did the right thing and would show my app when I shared only when I had all the selected apps as JPEG or PNGs. My app does not get listed in the list of apps if I had even one file other than JPEG or PNG.
- Google download on my LG Nexus 5 did something strange. I app would not be listed if I shared after selecting only PDFs other anything other than images but it would list my app of I selected a combination. Like if I selected a JPEG, two PDFs, one.HTML file etc. All it needed was at least one JPEG or PNG in the list of files to be shared.

I had all these combinations of different behaviors. I think the best way to handle this was to gate the files inside my app. So here is what I wrote -

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(receivedIntent.getAction()) && receivedIntent.getType() != null){

                String type = receivedIntent.getType();
                ArrayList<Uri> filesListTemp = new ArrayList<>(filesList);
                // MimeTypes.ALL is */* - the mimetype passed when multiple files are passed as the shared received intent. If only Images then it would be image/*.
                if(TextUtils.equals(type, MimeTypes.ALL)){
                // Here filesListTemp is getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                    for(Uri fileURI : filesListTemp){
                        String mimeType = getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(fileURI);
                        Log.d(TAG, "mimeType of the file : " + mimeType);
                        if(mimeType != null){
                            if(!TextUtils.equals(mimeType, MimeTypes.JPG) && !TextUtils.equals(mimeType, MimeTypes.PNG)){
                                filesList.remove(fileURI);
                            }
                        } else {
                            String filePath = fileURI.getPath().toLowerCase();
                            if (!filePath.endsWith(".jpg") && !filePath.endsWith(".jpeg") && !filePath.endsWith(".png")) {
                                filesList.remove(fileURI);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Don't forget to handle the case where all fileURIs is removed. Don't want to get NullPointers. Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my case is very different. My app will allow all type of file like video, audio , document , pdf and image(both single/multiple) . But if I receive a file from Google drive I am getting exception in file extension. I cant get the file type and its extension. Do you have any idea on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
val fileUri: ArrayList<Uri> = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as ArrayList<Uri> /* = java.util.ArrayList<android.net.Uri> */
            for (i in fileUri){
                var mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(i))
                if (mimeType.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    mimeType = "oga"
                }
                val fileName = "${i.lastPathSegment}.$mimeType"
                sendOtherFile(i, fileName)
            }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please [edit] it.